# Ubuntu 18.04 theme: how can I change the default color?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and changed my GTK theme to Adwaita Dark. But how to change the GNOME theme? Because it is still the same, with this orange color and a different gray.

I explored CompizConfig and Dconfig without success. I want to change manually the status bar color and the accent color. How?

A screenshot of my desktop with the two themes... not good.

[image: various colours in theme]

Comment: first install Gnome shell extension "User Themes" then down load gnome shell themes from gnome-look.org website and follow the instructions where to store them. then change shell themes via gnome tweaks.

Comment: You can change the default colors of the theme by modifying this file : /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css

Comment: As an exemple, if you want the default gnome theme (with blue colors instead of orange) replace 'ubuntu.css' by 'gnome-shell.css' in the file '/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json'. The file 'gnome-shell.css' is located in '/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/'

Comment: And then restart `gnome-shell` with `ALT+F2` and type `restart`.